# Biblatex \footcite with split on two pages hyperref assign the link to the whole page

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, footnotes

In my document the link in the footnote is divided into two parts which are placed on the following pages. Then the `hyperref` mark as a link the whole main text laying between these two parts of link:

[image][image][image]

How to prevent such marking of the text? Is it possible to apply the @David Carlisle solution [(link)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347291/footnotes-split-on-two-pages-with-hyperlink) which concerns to the `\footnote`? Does exist the solution for the similar problem in which the citation is placed in text? [(link)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330669/cite-hyperlink-across-two-pages)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mylist.bib}
@inbook{roadrunner,
    author =    {Geococcyx californianus},
    url =       {https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350872/moving-short-bibstring-to-the-next-line-of-footnote-citation}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mylist.bib}

\begin{document}
Aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa\footcite{roadrunner} \blindtext.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround could be to use package `bigfoot` like this:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{roadrunner,
  author = {Geococcyx californianus},
  url    = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350872/moving-short-bibstring-to-the-next-line-of-footnote-citation}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=5cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{bigfoot} % <==============================================
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
Aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa\footcite{roadrunner} 
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting page]

Comment: Thx for the response. I prefer to place footnote mark on the same page as the beginning of corresponding footnote.